# How to animate menu background changing image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to animate when i hover a li.. background image will be the zoom out

```js
$(function () {
    var image = $('.menu').find('img').attr('src');
    $('.menu ul li').mouseover(function () {
        var currentImage = $(this).attr('data-img');
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('img').attr('src', currentImage); })});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar{display: none; visibility: hidden;}
body{margin: 0; background: burlywood; }
.menu {  position: relative;  text-align: center;  margin: auto;  height: 100%;  padding-top: 2%;  padding-bottom: 10%; z-index: 99;}
.menu li{ display: block; font-size: 1.5rem; font-family: "Raleway SemiBold", Serif, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 20px;}
.menu li+li{margin-top: 30px;}
.menu a{ font-size: 3.5rem;}
.navigationGif{ position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; animation: menuBG 0.7s ease-in;}
.homeGif{ position: fixed;}
.menu img{ width: 100%; }
@keyframes menuBG { from{ opacity: 0; transform: scale(1.05); }}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
        <div class="navigationGif">
            <div class=""> <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532109513327-3b32b2a9bd57?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="" class="src"> </div> </div>
        <div class="menu"> <div class="data"><ul>
                 <li>Navigation</li>
<li data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532109513327-3b32b2a9bd57?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" class="navLink home active"><a href="" class="navItem"><span>H</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span></a></li>
<li data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589986118236-64c32953ab27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" class="navLink works"><a href="" class="navItem">Works</a></li>
<li data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589892889837-e0236f8dd22e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=753&q=80" class="navLink about"><a href="" class="navItem">About</a></li>
<li data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558567083-b8cb6bb5f7d9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=763&q=80" class="navLink contact"><a href="" class="navItem">Contact</a></li></ul> </div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset the animation, also avoid too many parent() call as possible by select closest element or create better class names.
So here I make a small modification to get what you need, by add a class name to the background img that trigger animation, every time you change the hover to other menu item (LI element) it will toggle the class name so the animation will restart each time.

```js
$(function () {
  var image = $('.menu').find('img').attr('src');
  var lastImage
  $('.menu ul li.navLink').mouseover(function () {
    var currentImage = $(this).attr('data-img');
    $('.navigationGif img').attr('src', currentImage);
    if(lastImage !== currentImage) {
      $('.navigationGif').removeClass('animation')
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('.navigationGif').addClass('animation')
      }, 10);
      lastImage = currentImage
    }
  })
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: burlywood;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: "Raleway SemiBold", Serif, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu li+li {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.menu a {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.navigationGif {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.navigationGif.animation {
  animation: menuBG 0.7s ease-in;
}

.homeGif {
  position: fixed;
}

.menu img {
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes menuBG {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="navigationGif animation">
    <div class=""> <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532109513327-3b32b2a9bd57?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"
        alt="" class="src"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="data">
      <ul>
        <li>Navigation</li>
        <li
          data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532109513327-3b32b2a9bd57?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"
          class="navLink home active"><a href=""
            class="navItem"><span>H</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span></a></li>
        <li
          data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589986118236-64c32953ab27?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"
          class="navLink works"><a href="" class="navItem">Works</a></li>
        <li
          data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589892889837-e0236f8dd22e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=753&q=80"
          class="navLink about"><a href="" class="navItem">About</a></li>
        <li
          data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558567083-b8cb6bb5f7d9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=763&q=80"
          class="navLink contact"><a href="" class="navItem">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```